# backing up gpg media choice?

Tags: linux, backup, gpg

I am finally doing what I should have does years ago and producing a paper and digital backup of my keys.  The question is about the preferred media.  I have had usb thumb drives go bad but never had a cf/sd card go bad but that could be a function of the fact I have never used them much.  My plan is to purchase a new card of drive and then format it remove any manufacture installed auto launchers or anything else and then export the keys and then this will sit in a safe and hopefully will never need it.  Any suggestions?

TL;DR Is there a preferred media to store backups on?

Thank you,
Jason